# Measure time taken by Angular to render a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way I can measure the amount of time it took Angular to render a directive?

Or even simpler, is there a way I can tell how much time it took Angular to detect a change in a data set and render the content of the new data set?

For example, let's say I have this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.text }} 
</div>
```

How can I know how much time it takes between each dataset-change in `items` and the last DOM-related operation?

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [Angular Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk)? It has many performance testing tools for AngularJS apps. E.g. it can show you the time of the recent digest cycles and the most expensive watchers as well.

[image: Batarang example]

Note: I have tested in on [this pen](http://codepen.io/fracz/pen/KVbEzz) with your code and simple button.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.text }} 
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not seing anything in the extension (after enabling it and restarting Chrome). Does this work on Linux/Chrome 48?

Comment: Anyways, this is not really showing the rendering performance/time. This is only the watcher part. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It meaaures the total time of last digest cycle of Angular. Watchers are the heaviest part of it. Ot should work in any Chrome - there should be an AngularJS tab in your Developer Tools. You need to select the checkbox near the *Performance* there to start profiling.